# Using a client proxy object to call a WCF service from jQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf, web-services, proxy

We have a ASP.NET website project. In the past, we had been using asmx webservice. Now, we have WCF service, and I am trying to call a WCF service using client proxy object with jQuery. With asmx, it was fairly easy to call a webservice with folllowing lines of code

```
function GetBooks() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http: /WebService.asmx/GetBooks",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: onSuccess
    });
}
```

and the method in WebService class is

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public Books[] GetBooks()
{
       List<BooksTO> dtos = BooksDTOUtils.GetBooks(entityOwnerID);
       return dtos.ToArray();
}
```

Now, GetBooks_Wcf() method has to be called from jQuery. I am using a client proxy in new class (WcfCall.cs) to call wcf method GetBooks

```
  public Books[] GetBooksWcf()
{
        var service = WcfProxy.GetServiceProxy();
        var request = new GetBooksRequest();
        request.entityOwnerID= entityOwnerID;
        var response = service.GetBooks(request);
        returnresponse.Results.ToArray();
}
```

and my Proxy (Wcfproxy.cs) is

```
 public static Service.ServiceClient GetServiceProxy()
{
    var Service = Session["Service"] as Service.ServiceClient;
    if (Service == null)
    {
        // create the proxy
        Service = CreateServiceInstance();

        // store it in Session for next usage
        Session["Service"] = Service;
    }

    return Service;
}

   public static Service.ServiceClient CreateServiceInstance()
   {
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(IgnoreCertificateErrorHandler);

    string configValue = Environment.GetConfigSettingStr("WcfService");

    Service.ServiceClient webService = new Service.ServiceClient();
    //Here is my WCF endpoint
    webService.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(configValue);

    return webService;
}
```

So, my question is how do I call GetBooksWcf from jQuery? I have created a reference.cs, and Service.ServiceClient from above method is in reference.cs below. Also, the parameter "entityOwnerID" is sensitive and I cannot pass it from JQuery, either I have to persist it or call from web.config as key.

```
 [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
  public partial class ServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Service.IService>, Service.IService
  {
      .........  
   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET proxy for your WCF service cannot be used as-is in jQuery.

You need to enable your WCF service to be consumed via JavaScript or jQuery by using `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements` and `WebInvoke` attributes (see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link. However, in the link, the WCF service is called as                                                             `function WCFJSON() { var userid = "1";
   ..
    Url = "Service.svc/GetUser";
    Data = '{"Id": "' + userid + '"}';
   ..
   ..
  .}` You see how userid is hardcoded. I cannot pass parameter from jQuery(as userid is sensitive information, and i have to call a class method to get that. At this time, I end up using asmx as `url: "http: /WebService.asmx/GetBooks",`, and call my proxy class from there. Any better idea?

Comment: jQuery calls are transmitted over the wire, with the same security as any other client side element in your application. If you intend to keep user-id 'secure', you could still do it with WCF, provided you store user-id in Session or an equivalent server side storage. Or maybe just rely on the transport security (like HTTPS).